# How can i "load more" data by categories and not all together

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question is : how can i load more data by categories only and not all together? For example i select number 2 after i got result i need to load more data but only for number 2 filter.
Thanx in advance.

html -

```
number:
<select class="filterby">
  <option value="all">all</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

type:
<select class="filterby">
  <option value="all">all</option>
  <option value="plastic">plastic</option>
  <option value="metal">metal</option>
</select>

<br>

<div id="filter-content">

  <div class="all 1 plastic">1 plastic</div>
  <div class="all 1 metal">1 metal</div>
  <div class="all 2 plastic">2 plastic</div>
  <div class="all 2 metal">2 metal</div>
  <div class="all 3 plastic">3 plastic</div>
  <div class="all 3 metal">3 metal</div>

</div>

<br>

<div id="load-more">Load more</div>
```

js here

```
 $("select.filterby").change(function() {
     var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e) {
      return $(e).val();
      }).join(".");
      $("div#filter-content").find("div").hide();
      $("div#filter-content").find("div." + filters).show();
    });


    size = $("#filter-content div").size();
    x = 3;
    $('#filter-content div:lt(' + x + ')').show();
    $('#load-more').click(function() {
      x = (x + 1 <= size) ? x + 1 : size;
      $('#filter-content div:lt(' + x + ')').show();
      if (x == size) {
        $('#load-more').hide();
      }
    });
```

jsfiddle demo : https://jsfiddle.net/mrdoe/7smz31ad/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining `filters` outside of `change` handler, using `filters` as part of selector at `#load-more` `click` handler

```js
var filters = "all", size = $(".all").length, x = 3;
$("select.filterby").change(function() {
  x = 3;
  filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e) {
    return $(e).val();
  }).join(".");
  $("div#filter-content div").hide();
  $("div#filter-content div." + filters + ":lt("+x+")").show();
  size = $("#filter-content div." + filters).length;
  $("#load-more").show()
});

$("#filter-content div:lt(" + x + ")").show();
$("#load-more").click(function() {
  x = (x + 1 <= size) ? x + 1 : size;
  $("#filter-content div." + filters + ":lt(" + x + ")")
    .show(250, function() {
      if (x == size) {
        $("#load-more").hide(250);
        x = 3;
      }
    })
});
```

```css
#filter-content div {
  display: none;
}
#load-more {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#load-more:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
name:
<select class="filterby">
  <option value="all">all</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

type:
<select class="filterby">
  <option value="all">all</option>
  <option value="plastic">plastic</option>
  <option value="metal">metal</option>
  <option value="glass">glass</option>
</select>

<br>

<div id="filter-content">

  <div class="all 1 plastic">1 plastic</div>
  <div class="all 1 metal">1 metal</div>
  <div class="all 1 glass">1 glass</div>
  <div class="all 2 plastic">2 plastic</div>
  <div class="all 2 plastic">2 plastic</div>
  <div class="all 2 plastic">2 plastic</div>
  <div class="all 2 plastic">2 plastic</div>
  <div class="all 2 plastic">2 plastic</div>
  <div class="all 2 metal">2 metal</div>
  <div class="all 2 metal">2 metal</div>
  <div class="all 2 metal">2 metal</div>
  <div class="all 2 metal">2 metal</div>
  <div class="all 2 metal">2 metal</div>
  <div class="all 2 metal">2 metal</div>
  <div class="all 2 glass">2 glass</div>
  <div class="all 3 plastic">3 plastic</div>
  <div class="all 3 metal">3 metal</div>
  <div class="all 3 glass">3 glass</div>

</div>

<br>

<div id="load-more">Load more</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7smz31ad/6/

Comment: thank you , can you show an example of using filters as a part of load more ?

Comment: @mrdoe _"can you show an example of using filters as a part of load more ?"_ Not certain interpret correctly ? What do you mean by "as part of a load more" ?

Comment: @mrdoe `$('#filter-content div.'+filters+':lt(' + x + ')').show();`

Comment: What is expected result ? If select `2` only elements having `className` `2` are displayed

Comment: the point is to load more data only then we select specific category , for example i selected name : 2 type : plastic it giving me 1 result if i want load more data in name 2 type plastic only i click on load more and this is not works

Comment: @mrdoe _" for example i selected name : 2 type : plastic it giving me 1 result if i want load more data in name 2 type plastic only i click on load more and this is not works"_ The is only one element that has both `2` and `plastic` `className`s. Given `html` at Question and expected result, which elements other than those having `2` and `plastic` as `className` should be selected when "load more" is clicked with `2` and `plastic` are already selected categories?

Comment: @mrdoe See updated post. Added additional `plastic` and `metal` elements having `className` `2`. Try clicking `Load more` when `2` and `plastic` or `metal` are selected categories.

Comment: One more thing : can you add animation(fidein) when we select some category ? Thnx in advance.

Comment: Sorry i found some problem : at first page loading load more btn is not working , and it should load + 1 data only , when we loaded all data load more btn need to be inactive and when we choosing another select name load more btn should be active again without refreshing page (please help)